# java down counter class

Tags: java, multithreading, countdowntimer

I have implemented a down counter in java in a separate class that has a starting time in seconds to start down counting to zero but when it does reach the zero I need it to make some thread in other file to stop do their jobs how could I do that?

here is my counter code:

```
public class Stopwatch {
    static int interval;
    static Timer timer;

    public void start(int time) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;
        timer = new Timer();
        interval =time; 
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
               // System.out.println(setInterval());
                setInterval();
            }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    public int time() {
        return interval;
    }

    private static final int setInterval() {
        if (interval == 1)
            timer.cancel();
        return --interval;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: [Thread interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: Depending on what the other thread is doing, I'd suggest interrupts or having a boolean value set (and checked in the other thread).  If execution of the other thread can be stopped at any time use an interrupt, however if execution cannot be stopped after a certain point in time, simply set/check a boolean before that code is entered.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, Exception InterruptedException is not compatible with throws clause in TimerTask.run()

Comment: @niiraj Are there no other ways to handle exceptions?

Comment: how to set a Boolean variable ? because the thread and the counter class are separated!

Comment: @flashdisk, just have a boolean class variable and a public getter for that variable.  Call the getter from the other class to check if it should continue.

`private static boolean continue = true;`
`public static boolean shouldContinue() { return this.continue; }`
`if (!(Stoopwatch.shouldContinue())) then return;`

Comment: how can the count down timer notify all the threads at once to stop working?!

Comment: @user3507600 should I do any imports to the other class?!

Comment: Yes, you need to import Stopwatch, unless it's in the same package then you should be fine.  Are you using an IDE?  If so, it should take care of that (since so few people program java in notepads anymore).

Comment: @user3507600 they are in the same package!, what is the IDE anyway?! thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what the other thread is doing, I'd suggest interrupts or having a boolean value set (and checked in the other thread). If execution of the other thread can be stopped at any time use an interrupt, however if execution cannot be stopped after a certain point in time, simply set/check a boolean before that code is entered.

Add a boolean to your stopwatch class:

```
private static boolean continue = true;
```

Create a method to check the boolean:

```
public static boolean shouldContinue() {
    return this.continue;
}
```

Modify your `setInterval()` to change the boolean:

```
private static final int setInterval() {
    if (interval == 1)
        continue = false;
    return --interval;
}
```

Add the check somewhere in your other class:

```
if (!(Stopwatch.shouldContinue())) {
    return;
}
```

or

```
if (Stopwatch.shouldContinue()) {
    //do work here
}
```

Since it sounds like my comments helped, I thought I'd make it into an answer so we can remove this from the unanswered list.